# Asynchronous Callback to Array.map()

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I've just started learning Node.js a few weeks ago.... I am not able to understand why the *'products'* array contains **null** instead of the desired objects....

On Line 13, when I am console logging the object, I get the desired object but I don't understand why they are **null** when I console log them on Line 40 after the map function has completed it's execution....

If the array length is 2 (which should imply successful pushing) why are the objects stored inside still **null** instead of the objects that I wanted to store ?

Console Output

[image: Console Output]

Order Schema

[image: Order Schema]

```
exports.getOrders = async (req, res, next) => {
  const userOrders = [];
  Order.find({ 'user.userId': req.user._id }).then((orders) => {
    console.log(orders); // Line 4
    async.eachSeries(
      orders,
      function (order, callback) {
        const products = order.products.map((p) => {
          const seriesId = p.product.seriesId;
          const volumeId = p.product.volumeId;
          Series.findById(seriesId).then((series) => {
            const volume = series.volumes.id(volumeId);
            console.log(volume, p.quantity); // Line 13
            return {
              seriesTitle: volume.parent().title,
              volume: volume,
              quantity: p.quantity
            };
          });
        });
        console.log('Product Array Length: ', products.length); // Line 21
        if (products.length !== 0) {
          const data = {
            productData: products,
            orderData: {
              date: order.date,
              totalPrice: order.totalPrice
            }
          };
          userOrders.push(data);
          callback(null);
        } else {
          callback('Failed');
        }
      },
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Could not retrieve orders'); 
        } else {
          console.log(userOrders);  // Line 40
          res.render('shop/orders', {
            docTitle: 'My Orders',
            path: 'orders',
            orders: userOrders,
            user: req.user
          });
        }
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: Don't mix *async.js* callback style with promises. You're already using `async`/`await` syntax, so just write a loop instead of using `async.eachSeries`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In line 8, `order.products.map` returns an array of null. Because this is an asynchronous mapping. For each product, you are calling `Series.findById` which is a promise and it only returns the value when it resolves. As you are not waiting for the promise to resolve, so it returns null on each iteration.

You have to map all the promises first then call `Promise.all` to resolve them and after that, you will get the expected value.

```js
exports.getOrders = async (req, res, next) => {
  const userOrders = [];
  Order.find({ 'user.userId': req.user._id }).then((orders) => {
    console.log(orders); // Line 4
    async.eachSeries(
      orders,
      function (order, callback) {
        const productPromise = order.products.map((p) => {
          const seriesId = p.product.seriesId;
          const volumeId = p.product.volumeId;
          //ANSWER:  Return the following promise
          return Series.findById(seriesId).then((series) => {
            const volume = series.volumes.id(volumeId);
            console.log(volume, p.quantity); // Line 13
            return {
              seriesTitle: volume.parent().title,
              volume: volume,
              quantity: p.quantity
            };
          });
        });
        // ANSWER: call all the promises
        Promise.all(productPromise)
        .then(function(products) {
            console.log('Product Array Length: ', products.length);
            if (products.length !== 0) {
            const data = {
              productData: products,
              orderData: {
                date: order.date,
                totalPrice: order.totalPrice
              }
            };
            userOrders.push(data);
            callback(null);
          } else {
            callback('Failed');
          }
        });
      },
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Could not retrieve orders'); 
        } else {
          console.log(userOrders);  // Line 40
          res.render('shop/orders', {
            docTitle: 'My Orders',
            path: 'orders',
            orders: userOrders,
            user: req.user
          });
        }
      }
    );
  });
};
```